# C++/parquet: How to write "Map" data (nested type)?

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

Based on the "StreamWriter" example ([stream_reader_writer](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/examples/parquet/parquet_stream_api/stream_reader_writer.cc)), I'm trying to add another column to the parquet schema which I want to write "Map-Data" (`Map<Integer, String>`) to.

According to [this source](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#maps), maps are supported by the C++ implementation. However, it's not clear to me how to ...

- correctly add/define another column of type "Map" to the parquet schema. According to the previous link, Maps are "Logical Types", so my best try so far is

  `fields.push_back(parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode::Make("Map", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED, parquet::LogicalType::Map(), parquet::Type::INT64));`

This compiles without error but I'm uncertain about the last parameter "primitive_type" (parquet::Type::INT64).

- how to define and write actual Map values. Again, the second links provides a general description of a parquet Map:

[image: Map]

The [github repo](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/cpp) is missing a C++ example (or test case) on how to use a Map/Logical Types. I'm looking for advice/an C++ example, how to define and use a Map.

Comment: The stream API does not support nested types.  You either need to use the low level API or the arrow API